# MacBook Pro stuck on grey screen with Apple logo and spinning wheel

Tags: macos, startup

The only thing it will let me do is booting to Safe Mode. After running `/sbin/fsck_hfs -drfy /dev/disk0s2` it returned with an incorrect number of extended attributes (it should be 486802 instead of 486801) and disk0s2: i/o error. `**the volume macintosh could not be verified completely.**`

Running the command once more it returns:

```
**the volume macintosh could not be verified completely.**
volume check failed with error 5
volume type is pure HFS+
primary MDB is at block 0 0x00
alternate MDB is at block 0 0x00
primary VHB is at block 2 0x02
alternate VHB is at block 623463230 0x25294b3e
sector size = 512 0x200
volumeObject flags = 0x07
total sectors for volume = 623463232 0x25294b40
total sectors for embedded volume - 0 0x00
checkHFS returned 5, fsmodified = 1
*****the volume was modified *****
doing update / reload mount for / now
:/root#

sw_vers: Mac OS X 10.9.5
```

I don't know what to do now. I really am trying to do this myself without spending any money or as little as possible. And I cannot do anything that will wipe out all of the info that is on it.

Comment: The key there is the error "volume check failed with error 5"  This is more often than not a physical hard drive failure - meaning you will have to get a new drive.  I wrote an [answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/231920/119271) that is applicable to your question.  Also, you might want to take a look at [Repair disk from single user mode (fsck fails)](http://bit.ly/2bWiX3s) as it is vert similar and relevant to your situation.

Comment: Also you should  check your drive's SMART status to verify if it has any errors.  Issue this command in Terminal:  `diskutil info disk0 | grep -i smart` and post the results.

Answer (score 1):

I/O errors are usually bad news- often a sign of failing hardware. :(

If you don't have a backup already be sure to make one ASAP. For example, try booting in [target disk mode](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22135?locale=en_US) (hold the `T` key while starting up) and connecting to another Mac. From there make a copy and try running Disk Utility to repair the volume.